# Forward declaration of struct for Boost graph typedef c++

Tags: c++, boost, forward-declaration, circular-reference

**Short problem description:**

Basically I want

```
struct Type;
typedef container<Type> MyType;
struct Type{
    MyType::sometype member;
}
```

Now, how do I do this?

**Actual problem:**

For the [Boost Succesive Shortest Path](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/successive_shortest_path_nonnegative_weights.html) algorithm, I need to have my forward edges mapped to their reverse. I have the following code:

```
struct VertexProperty { };
struct EdgeProperty;
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, VertexProperty, EdgeProperty> DirectedGraph;

struct EdgeProperty {
    double edge_capacity; //capacity: 1 for forward, 0 for reverse
    double edge_weight; //cost
    DirectedGraph::edge_descriptor reverse_edge; //reverse edge mapping

    //forward edge constructor:
    EdgeProperty(double distance, DirectedGraph::edge_descriptor reverseEdge) :
            edge_capacity(1), edge_weight(distance), reverse_edge(reverseEdge) {
    };

    //reverse edge constructor
    EdgeProperty(double distance) :
            edge_capacity(0), edge_weight(-distance) {
    };

};
```

However, now I get the following error:

```
/usr/include/boost/pending/property.hpp:35:7: error: ‘boost::property<Tag, T, Base>::m_value’ has incomplete type
../src/Tester.cpp:21:8: error: forward declaration of ‘struct EdgeProperty’
```

I guess this makes sense: for the DirectedGraph::edge_descriptor I need the full type of EdgeProperty, but that one is of course not initialized. How do I resolve this circular reference?

Comment: Looks useful: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list_traits.html

Comment: @aschepler That could very well be the solution to my problem... I'm trying it out now.

Comment: @aschepler Yup, that was it! I would accept it as the solution if you'd post it as an answer xD

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that `struct Type` cannot be defined (up to sizes and memory lay-out) `until container<Type>` is instantiated and defined, but that depends on the definition of `struct Type`.... leading to a circular dependency.

Break the dependency using a pointer or a smart pointer whose size and layout can be determined before defining its pointed-to type.

For example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct Type;
typedef std::vector<Type> MyType;
struct Type{
    std::shared_ptr<MyType::value_type> member;
};

int main() {
        Type t;
}
```

And you can refer to [When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration) for more details about forward declarations...

Comment: In my case, the object is sometimes purposefully left undefined. Can `shared_ptr` deal with this? Because `MyType::value_type & member` does not work.